Let $ G $ be a Lie group and $ H $ a connected subgroup of $ G $. If $ N_G(H)/H $ is finite does that imply $ H $ must be closed in $ G $?
Let $ G $ be a Lie group and $ H $ a connected subgroup of $ G $. If $ N_G(H)/H $ is finite does that imply $ H $ must be closed in $ G $?
The assumption that $ N_G(H)/H $ is finite cannot be weakened to $ N_G(H)/H $ closed in $ G/H $, since for example we can take $ G=T^2 $ and $ H $ the line with irrational slope on the torus. Then $ N_G(H)=G $ and so $ N_G(H)/H=G/H $ is certainly closed in $ G/H $, but  $ H $ is not closed in $ G $.
Also the assumption that $ H $ is connected is necessary, for example as suggested by Moishe Kohan we can take $ G=SL(2,\mathbb{R}) $ and $ H=SL(2,\mathbb{Q}) $ then $ N_G(H)=H $ and so $ N_G(H)/H=1 $ is finite but $ H $ is not closed in $ G $.
This question was suggested by @LSpice who brought up that the question Normalizer of connected subgroup contained in the Weyl group? might need the assumption that $ H $ is closed. But since $ N_G(H)/H $ is already assumed to be finite, and $ H $ assumed connected, perhaps that already implies that $ H $ must be closed?

In E.S.Thomas's paper "Connected subgroups of Lie groups" the following theorem is shown:
"THEOREM: Let G be a connected Lie group of dimension greater than one. Then G has a connected subgroup which is dense in G and which is not an analytic
subgroup."
